# Firebase 9 & Flutter: How to initializeApp?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am desperately trying to figure out how to initializeApp with Flutter (not React Native).

I know about the functions to use, but I can not find the firebaseConfig I need to pass into the function.

And no matter what I search for, every resources references to React Native, like as if nobody codes with Flutter since Firebase 9 has been released anymore (or I am the only dummy which is not able to resolve this by myself).

Can someone tell me where to get the firebaseConfig object from?

If I add a new app to my project, I only get the google-services.json, which does NOT include the firebaseConfig object I need to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your confusion now, let me explain. When the guy in the video talks about Firebase v9 he is talking about the SDK version which in the case of Javascript (which I suppose is his main topic in his channel) is currently 9.17.1 an the version 9 has been around since 2021 so it is not new. The different SDKs have their own versions for each platform so thinking it will be the same in every SDK is a mistake by itself. You can check the SDKS [here.](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) So there is no Firebase v9, there is a Firebase SDK **for javascript** version 9. They managed in that way in javascript and in flutter it is not the same. Being that the last update in the flutter SDK was literally yesterday I'm pretty sure they have their reasons to not implement the same functions in flutter since 2021.

Now, one of the thinks the guy talks in the video is deconstructing, which is something common in javascript. The way you do this in flutter is by using `show`.

So you would be doing this for example:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart' show FirebaseFirestore, QuerySnapshot; //Add everything you would be using
```

This way only the specific parts of the library will be imported and the amount of code the Dart VM has to load will be reduced.

As of the access to documents, it is still the same but you can easily create a helper class that contents your references to your collections and then just use that class to reduce the boilerplate code created by the firebase SDK.

Comment: Answered my qustion fully, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the Firebase CLI and run `firebase init`.

You need to use the package `firebase_core` that will give you access to the class `Firebase` so you can use it to initialize your app `Firebase.initializeApp()` you can pass the default options for the current platform using `Firebase.initilizeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform)` usually your IDE will automatically import the corresponding package but in case it does not you would have to `import 'firebase/firebase_options.dart';`

An useful link to the documentation: [Add Firebase to your Flutter App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SFJsgSPzsYI&t=112s at 2:00 you can see the new Firebase 9 way of initializeApp. It is no longer a method but a function. At 2:35 he explains about the functions that can be used instead of the methods. But I just cant make it work with Flutter instead of React.